# Copy just the Id of one table to another

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to use the Primary key Id of table SourceTable to DestTable. SourceTable autogenerates the unique Id and I have to insert this Id to DestTable.  System.DateTime.Now(I am working with Asp.net C#) value is the only unique data that can refer to this Id. Below is my query:

```
string @Date = ("Select Id from SourceTable Where Date=' " + System.DateTime.Now + " '");
string insertId = "insert into DestTable (Id) SELECT Id FROM SourceTable WHERE Date= ' " + Date + " ' ";
SqlCommand comId = new SqlCommand(insertId, conn);
```

When I execute this command, my DestTable's Id column is empty. What is my solution?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Its a SQL database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use two queries for this?  Just use:

```
insert into DestTable (d)
    select id
    from SourceTable
    where date = CURRENT_DATE;
```

Your code is probably not returning an answer because `now()` has a time component and that prevents the date from matching the constant.

Notes:  `CURRENT_DATE` depends on the database.  This might be `trunc(sysdate)` (Oracle), `cast(getdate() as date)` (SQL), or something else.